# VS Code: NPM Works Great at the Command Line, but "NPM Scripts" Pane Gets "/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found"

Tags: linux, npm, visual-studio-code

I have Node/NPM installed on my (Linux) system.  When I use an ordinary terminal, or the terminal inside VS Code, I can run `npm` commands just fine.

However, when I try to use the "NPM Scripts" feature of VS Code (which lets you run your `package.json` scripts from a pane in the "Explorer"), I see:

> > Executing task in folder MyProject: npm run start <
>
> /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found The terminal process terminated with exit
>   code: 127
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

It seems like VS Code uses a different user/shell/path/something to run these scripts, and as a result it can't find the `npm` command ... but I have no idea what it's using or how to fix it.

Comment: Try adding the path to `npm` to your `$PATH` (https://askubuntu.com/a/109406/468670) so that `/bin/sh` can find it.

Comment: How can I do that for NPM tasks specifically?  Again, everything works fine normally: if I (for instance) open the Terminal inside VS Code and run `echo $PATH`, it includes `/home/me/.npm-global/bin` as expected.  It's *only* when running NPM scripts through the VS Code "NPM Scripts" feature that my `PATH` (or *something*) is off ... but I have no idea how to address it.

Comment: When running your terminal, run `/bin/sh` and then verify that you have `npm` in your `$PATH`. Each shell might be loaded differently and therefore might have different variables set.

Comment: In the terminal (in my regular OS one or in VS Code's) ... whether I run `/bin/sh` first or not ... when I `echo $PATH` the path to the `npm` folder (specifically `home/me/.npm-global/bin`) *is* present. And that makes sense, because I can run `npm` fine in all those cases.  It is **only** when I'm specifically running NPM Tasks through VS Code that there is a problem, and in that instance I unfortunately can't determine what my `$PATH` is, because there's no way to run terminal commands via that mechanism.

Comment: In the dev tools `process.env.PATH`  includes `home/me/.npm-global/bin`.  It seems like that's yet another way of checking what VS Code in general is doing, but since this issue seems  specific to running `package.json` scripts through VS Code's "NPM SCRIPTS" pane, these "general checks" don't seem to help.  The core to this issue seems to be "how are NPM scripts run *differently* in VS Code": does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason "NPM Scripts" function needs the npm file to be  in `/usr/local/bin/npm`. Try using your linux package manager to install npm (ex: sudo apt-get install npm) or install node.js again with the package from the website.

Another option would be to create a soft-link in `/usr/local/bin/` pointing to the current installation.

Comment: This was definitely the problem, thanks for the explanation.